# Javascript variable is undefined outside if condition

Tags: javascript

I have defined a javascript variable but it returns undefined.

```
variable = "";

if(somecondition){
      variable=myString.length;
}
alert(variable);
```

here variable returns undefined. If I keep the alert inside the if condition, I am able to get the value but its not working if I keep the alert outside the if condition.

Comment: var variable = '"";

Comment: declare var variable = "";

Comment: you missed adding var to it..did you define myString correctly...try adding var and check

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi I have tried using var variable also. But the result is the same.

Comment: @all — How does that help ?

Comment: Can you show what is myString and what exactly is your condition

Comment: `if` is NOT a loop.

Comment: Please make an example that illustrates your exact problem. [I threw this together](https://jsfiddle.net/gap4xbhL/) (making some simple assumptions) and your code works as you would expect it to.

Comment: myString is not defined , define it outside as var myString =[]

Comment: @nive32 Why would you make `myString` an array?

Comment: @nive32 `myString` is defined, but it hasn't `length` property. If it wasn't defined, there would occur an error, and the alert would never be executed.

Comment: @Teemu , yes i agree, that should be the one assigning the undefined value

Answer (score 1):

Your `myString` does not have an property called `length` and hence you are getting `undefined`.
Usually, `String`, `array` has `length` property while objects don't have it.

Either you are invoking a wrong property or invoking it on a wrong data type or you have to define one yourself :P

Comment: That's what I said!

Answer (score 0):

Using var will do it:

```
var variable;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare and define your variable.

```
var variable = "";

if(somecondition) {
      variable = myString.length;
}

alert(variable);
```

Comment: No. `var` isn't necessary, since all of the code is in the SAME scope.

Comment: ^ although you should definitely declare your variables with `var` (or some other declaration keyword) to avoid making globals.

Answer (score 0):

```
var variable = '';
if (true) {
     variable = 'Yes'
}
alert(variable);
```

This will show alert as Yes.

So in your case `myString.length;` is probably undefined

Comment: But I am able to see the vlue if I alert inside the if condition which means there is no problem with the string.

Comment: Which value can you see inside the if condition? The .length value? What is it?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing the initialization of mystring?

Look at the following

[image]

Comment: No. I have initialized the string in the same way. and I amble to see the value inside the condition

Comment: may be your condition is not valid or your mystring variable doesn't have length property

Answer (score 0):

Your statement is wrong inside the if statement.

your assignment is getting failure inside that, means you are assigning undefined inside the if statement anyhow as string.length is giving undefined.
if assignment was succe

try out this, it'll work:

```
variable = "";
if(somecondition){
  variable= 'not an empty string';
}
alert(variable);
```

you'll get the 'not an empty string'

Answer (score -1):

If variable isn't undefined in the function, it's because it is still equal to the initial value, "" (Empty String).

What I bet is happening, is myString is actually a number and not a string. Try the following and see if you are still having a problem:

```
variable = "";

if(somecondition){
      variable=myString.toString().length;
}
alert(variable);
```