# Javascript variable undefined outside if else condition

Tags: javascript, object, if-statement, javascript-objects

I have 2 objects coming from props and I am assigning these objects to their variable by if else condition

```
  let var1;
  let var2;

    if (props.id === 1) {
      var1 = props;
      console.log(var1); //  returns {id:1,learn:"HTML", do:"cooking"}
    } else {
      var2 = props;
    }

  console.log(var1); // returns {id:1,learn:"HTML", do:"cooking"} and undefined
```

When I `console.log` after condition why does it returns the object and `undefined`? But when `console.log` inside if condition only returns the object.

I want that it returns only the object if console.log after the condition

My two objects coming like this

```
{id:1,learn:"HTML", do:"cooking"}
{id:2,learn:"Css", do:"home-work"}
```

I have seen resources from StackOverflow

[Javascript variable is undefined outside if condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40049273/javascript-variable-is-undefined-outside-if-condition)

[JavaScript Variable undefined outside of function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41166941/javascript-variable-undefined-outside-of-function)

This question is said to be duplicate for [Chrome/Firefox console.log always appends a line saying 'undefined'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14633968/chrome-firefox-console-log-always-appends-a-line-saying-undefined)

but it's completely different it's not about the browsers console I am getting undefined from my javascript file

Comment: You never set `var1` if the else-statement is evaluated.

Comment: Where are you seeing the `undefined`? How are you executing this code?

Comment: @Bergi when I console the var1 after condition then I see the undefined in the console

Comment: You don't define it in all cases. If `props.id` is not 1, `var1` does not get defined.

Comment: I am sorry that's a mistake that I make while asking the question. I will correct it

Comment: @user1599011 now see the code

Comment: You still don't define `var1` in the else statement. What are you expecting it to be?

Comment: I expect var 1 to the object ```{id:1,learn:"HTML", do:"cooking"}```

Comment: Please include your `props` definition. Your code seem to be failing the if-statement, thus executing the else-statement and not defining `var1`.  A [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is needed to know exactly what's going on.

Answer (score -2):

Use **const** instead of **let** and try to differentiate the logs of next render from the previous render like this

```
const var1;
const var2;

if (props.id === 1) {
  var1 = data;
  console.log(var1);
} else {
  var2 = data;
}
console.log(var1);
console.log("--------");
```

Comment: we can not change the const variable it would give an error